# KIVY: Get widgets added during App initializing

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to develop a kivy app (==2.0.0). During the app initialization (when the command `Builder.load_string` is running), a splash screen is shown. I want every widget to be shown in that screen as it loads.

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Comment: It's possible, just write code to add widgets to the screen when you want. In practice they'll probably appear in a few ms after several seconds of splash screen.

Comment: kv string has several widgets. I added screen manager in build function. In start function I launch ```builder.load_string``` asynchronously: during that I'd like to show on screen widgets just loaded from kv string. My workaround is ruling ```on_parent``` in kv string to make it call a function that updates screen.